# APIGEE client.loginFacebook how to overwrite userid generated by apigee

Tags: javascript, facebook-login, apigee

when using client.loginFacebook is there a way to also send along a desired userid or do you have to allow apigee service to first create the userid (ie fb_$fbid) and then update that entry with the desired id.

Here is some context just in case my question is not clear. I want to allow users to login via Facebook and then want them to input a desired id. I then wish to call client.loginFacebook to save both the input userid and their facebook information.

Is this possible? (I guess I am simply trying to save an additional api call)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do the two calls. The login call does not allow for writing to the user object.

What happens is that during the login call, Usergrid calls facebook behind the scenes to verify the token and get the data. It creates a user if none exists already, then returns a usergrid oauth token.

You would have to make a second call to update the user object.